# Is there a connection between SourceSafe (version control) and SharePoint (collaboration)?

Tags: sharepoint, visual-sourcesafe

Or are they two distinct applications that are not related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are very different, although some people push the list of source control commits or latest files (head) to their team wiki (which could be SharePoint)

Answer (score 1):

SourceSafe and SharePoint have no connection, however Team Foundation Server and SharePoint do have a connection. For each new Team Project you create Team Foundation Server will create a project site that is a SharePoint (WSS) site. You can store whatever project information you would like there, as well as look at various statistics and reports related to your project from the site. The site can be useful for non-developers (anyone without Visual Studio and Team Explorer) to be able to view information about the project such as work items, reports, build statistics, etc.

Answer (score 0):

They are unrelated as Source Safe was created by a different company that MS acquired.  Team foundation server and SharePoint is a different story.  I believe that Team Foundation Server is an extension WSS.

Comment: TFS uses WSS for the team project portals, which is where all the documentation goes but that's it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe they are unrelated but both use SQL Server as their backend.

Comment: SourceSafe does not use SQL Server.  It uses it's own, file-based, database system.